# Can the Knight go through all spaces on a $7\times7$ chessboard?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, chessboard

On a $8\times8$ chessboard if the Knight starts at one of the corners it can move through all $64$ squares only once. But on a $7\times7$ board can the Knight go through all $49$ squares only once (need the route taken) If not why?

Comment: Does it return to the square it started on?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour#Existence

Comment: No it doesn't need to go back at the start

Comment: Then the Wikipedia article gives Warnsdorff's rule

Comment: @saulspatz A simple parity argument shows that it can't possibly return to its starting point.